# React.js handler function doesnt set state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simply wanted to do dynamic modal . When i click the button it works but doesnt set state immediately. First console.log returns empty array. Others work properly.

//State and handler

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState([])

const handleModal = (id) => {
    const modalData = data?.filter((item) => item.id == id )
    setShowModal(modalData)
    console.log(showModal)
}

console.log(showModal)
console.log(showModal)
```

Ive tried useEffect like that also

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [showModal])
```

Comment: state updates may be asynchronous - Check out these resources for more information:
https://gist.github.com/bpas247/e177a772b293025e5324219d231cf32c
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous
https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#render-batching-and-timing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two** things you need to know about the **state update** in React:

- State is updated asynchronously
- In any particular render, state and props don't change, changes are
  only reflected when component re-renders

If you want to log the updated value of `selected`, put the log statement in the `useEffect` hook.

You can't update and log the updated value of any state variable in the same render; component will have to re-render to reflect changes due to state update.

Similarly, if you want to call a function with the updated value of `selected`, call the function from inside the `useEffect` hook.